# How can I give access to my Amazon Mechanical Turk account to another user?

Tags: amazon

How can I give access to my Amazon Mechanical Turk (AMT) account to another user? The objectives is that:

1. The other user may run AMT experiments either through the AMT API or through the AMT web interface.
2. I want to be able to view the other user's experiment (e.g., see how many hits they've received) as well as pay for them through my AMT account.
3. Ideally, the other user shouldn't be able to view/edit the AMT experiments that they didn't initiated.

Comment: This question has being asking three times before [1](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/117460/88163), [2](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/136526/88163), [3](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/148969/88163). so, for it to be given a third opportunity for answering, it needs to have considerably more details included, like what the asker has done to try and answer it themselves.

Comment: Since you have >10k rep, instead of reposting the question you should undelete it and in order to prevent that it be deleted automatically again you should add more details as was mentioned in the previous comment.